# Scrolling after scrolling in recycler view

Tags: android

I would like to put a scrollable Recycler View, but at the end of the Recycler View, I would like to show other elements in the bottom of the scroll.

[image]

How can I do that ?

There is my code :

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recyclerView_card_elements"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="LOG OUT"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="18sp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Can you show your code what you have tried?

Answer (score 0):

maybe you need something like this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recyclerView_card_elements"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="LOG OUT"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="18sp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```